# Creating vCard QR Code

Tags: php, google-visualization, qr-code, vcf-vcard

I've got a PHP script that generates a business card template from details entered on the website.

We've recently decided to add QR Code vCards to the business cards as an easy way to save contact info. I am using [this](http://diginit.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/getting-vcard-info-into-a-qr-code-using-the-google-chart-api/) tutorial as a starting point.

However, my QR Code does not work. It keeps giving me no result and format as text.

Here is the script that creates the vcard and displays the qr code:

```
$vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:3.0\r\n
N:" . $_POST['surname'] . ";" . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n
FN:" . $_POST['name'] . " " . $_POST['surname'] . "\r\n
ORG:Example Organisation\r\n
TITLE:" . $_POST['position'] . " [" . $_POST['qualification'] . "]\r\n
TEL;TYPE=work,voice:" . $_POST['telephone'] . "\r\n
TEL;TYPE=cell,voice:" . $_POST['cellno'] . "\r\n
TEL;TYPE=work,fax:" . $_POST['fax'] . "\r\n
URL;TYPE=work:www.example.com\r\n
EMAIL;TYPE=internet,pref:" . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n
REV:" . date('Ymd') . "T195243Z\r\n
END:VCARD";

echo '<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=500x500&cht=qr&chld=H&chl="' . urlencode($vcard) . '"/>';
```

Any assistance?

Comment: Can you show the contents of `$vcard`?

Comment: It is shown here. Unless I'm not understanding you correctly.

Comment: Can you show the result in plain text rather than how it is generated? either than or provide an example link to the google chart you are retrieving?

Comment: Here is example data: `BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0 N:User;Test FN:Test User ORG:Example Organisation TITLE:asgfas [asgasg] TEL;TYPE=work,voice:2523626 TEL;TYPE=cell,voice:2365236 TEL;TYPE=work,fax:236236 URL;TYPE=work:www.example.com EMAIL;TYPE=internet,pref:testu@example.com REV:20121015T195243Z END:VCARD` as generated by the PHP script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The double quote is being encoded into the QR Code, it should work if you remove these (and should avoid error as any special characters are encoded).

Removing the quotes gives me this QR Code which seems to work:

[image: QR Code]

Comment: Great. Something as small as quotes... It's always something small. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Just change:

```
echo 'img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=500x500&cht=qr&chld=H&chl="' . urlencode($vcard) . '"/';
```

to:

```
echo 'img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=500x500&cht=qr&chld=H&chl=' . urlencode($vcard) . '"/';
```

This is because you are closing, with the " the SRC from the TAG `<img>`.